# apcupsd incorrectly detects UPS power status

Tags: ups, daemon

This is a brand new device (BGM1500B). It seems when it charges to 100% it starts to report STATUS : ONBATT. The device itself shows that it is hooked up to power on the display and I do not hear it clicking over to battery so it seems like it is not a hardware issue. I cannot figure out why daemon is reading the ONBATT signal.

I have messed with the sensitivity, tried two computers (one linux one macOS), as well as trying different wall outlets for powers source. Behavior is consistent across all changes, and nothing is standing out to me as a cause or a solution.

Below is the status when plugged into a powered outlet and charged to 100% (no load on the battery)

```
user|~: apcaccess status                                                                                                                                         9:04PM
APC      : 001,037,0926
DATE     : 2023-05-11 21:04:44 -0400  
HOSTNAME : device.home
VERSION  : 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) darwin
UPSNAME  : device.home
CABLE    : USB Cable
DRIVER   : USB UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2023-05-11 21:04:43 -0400  
MODEL    : Back-UPS BGM1500     
STATUS   : ONBATT 
LINEV    : 122.0 Volts
LOADPCT  : 0.0 Percent
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT : 180.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Low
LOTRANS  : 78.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 150.0 Volts
ALARMDEL : 30 Seconds
BATTV    : 27.6 Volts
LASTXFER : Low line voltage
NUMXFERS : 1
XONBATT  : 2023-05-11 21:04:45 -0400  
TONBATT  : 1 Seconds
CUMONBATT: 1 Seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : OK
STATFLAG : 0x05040010
SERIALNO :             
BATTDATE : 1980-01-01
NOMINV   : 120 Volts
NOMBATTV : 24.0 Volts
NOMPOWER : 900 Watts
FIRMWARE : 000000G0-313200S9
END APC  : 2023-05-11 21:04:46 -0400
```

Im new to APC / UPS devices as well as `apcaccess`/`apcupsd`/`apctest` so I am open to suggestions.

Cause doesn't seem to be low line voltage as LINEV always shows 120-122

I have seen one other report of this here: https://forums.unraid.net/topic/126485-apcupsd-shows-on-battery-any-time-its-fully-charged/ I would like to stick to `apcupsd` if possible since it is build into the OS (unRAID) but if I have to I will change. Should I be reaching out to APC?